How can I add Rstudio inside a docker image which already contains R packages
I installed Rstudio within my docker environment using the following code.
Here is the minimla docker script.
FROM nextflow/nextflow:22.10.6

#Python & Postgres
RUN yum search python3 \
    && yum search python3 | grep devel \
    && yum install python3 -y \
    && yum install postgresql-devel -y \
    && yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64 \
    && yum -y install gcc -y

#R
RUN yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -y \
    && yum install R -y \
    && yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel -y \
    && yum install curl-devel -y \
    && yum install libjpeg-turbo-devel -y \
    && yum install openssl-devel -y


#set working directory where all will be housed
WORKDIR /DIR

#install jupyter notebook
RUN pip3 install jupyter -U && pip3 install jupyterlab

#python packages e.g. aws
RUN pip3 install awscli

#AWS
RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id XXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    && aws configure set region XXXXXXX

#Allow c++ to be used with R
RUN mkdir -p ~/.R \
    && touch ~/.R/Makevars \
    && echo CXX17 = g++ >> ~/.R/Makevars \
    && echo CXX17PICFLAGS = -fpic >> ~/.R/Makevars \
    && echo CXX17STD = -std=gnu++17 >> ~/.R/Makevars

#install R packages e.g. reticulate
COPY ["./R/reticulate","/DIR/RPackages"]
RUN R -e "install.packages('/ec2-user/RPackages/RcppTOML_0.2.0.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')" \
    && R -e "install.packages('/ec2-user/RPackages/rprojroot_2.0.3.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')" \
    && R -e "install.packages('/ec2-user/RPackages/here_1.0.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')" \
    && R -e "install.packages('/ec2-user/RPackages/rappdirs_0.3.3.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')" \
    && R -e "install.packages('/ec2-user/RPackages/reticulate_1.27.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')"


#Install R studio
ENV USER=rstudio
ENV password=rstudio

RUN yum install -y wget gdebi-core \
    && wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos7/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm \
    && yum install -y rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm \
    && rm -f rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm

EXPOSE 8787
CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver","--server-daemonize=0", "--auth-none=0"]


RUN yum install -y wget gdebi-core \
    && wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos7/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm \
    && yum install -y rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm \
    && rm -f rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1717-x86_64.rpm

EXPOSE 8787

At the moment the Rstudio login page is stuck saying "Sign in fails".
There are a few main purposes of this docker images:

Be able to run Rstudio
Use reticulate within R to talk with python 3.7.16 which is installed as the default python3.
Be able to use jupyter lab also within this enviroment.


notes on past attempts below
CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver","--server-daemonize=0","--auth-none=1"]

My docker image already contains many R packages which have been stored in 'Home/rpackages/' directory. It also has a default python3.7. I would like this Rstudio to be able to interact with the rpackages and the python3.7 within the image.
When running the image "dockerfile"
docker run -p 8787:8787 dockerfile
http://localhost:8787/auth-sign-in?appUri=%2F website leads to
`
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
`
Any help in getting an Rstudio which can use the rpackages within the docker image would be very welcome.
Additional attempts included
ENV USER=rstudio
#Run final startup command
CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver","--server-daemonize=0","--server-data-dir=/home/$USER/rstudio-server", "--auth-none=1"]


Which lead to connection issues to the Rstudio server.
I also tried to include the username and password.
ENV USER=rstudio
ENV password=rstudio

#Run final startup command
CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver","--server-daemonize=0", "--auth-none=0"]

But the password and username were not being recognized.

Perhaps you'd be interested in the rocker project. You might even consider basing your container on one of theirs, e.g. FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.3.

Have you defined the USER environment variable as mentioned here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7575?

@FloydEverest I am interested in rocker, but a complete re-write of the docker image would be last resort, and improving it with access to Rstudio server would be ideal.

@MrFlick thank you for this link I attempted a few attempts based on this link, but think I am misunderstanding the syntax. I have updated my question to include more detail on my attempts.

Can you please provide a reproducible Dockerfile? How are you installing R itself?
